# Modal dialog window is not fully closed after clicking OK/Cancel on the list edit form

Tags: modal-dialog

The edit form is opened through a link. Once the user click this link, the edit form for the list will be opened as a modal dialog. Any changes done are saved but the modal dialog is not closed properly on Chrome and Firefox (see the exceptions below). On IE this works fine and no exception is thrown. What is the solution for this?

This error will appear on Chrome:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://vm-sp2010:700/Pages/The-Pipeline.aspx from frame with URL
>   http://vm-sp2010/my/personal/administrator/Lists/ClockSettings/EditForm.aspx?ID=1&IsDlg=1.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

This error is on Firefox:

> Error: Permission denied for http://vm-sp2010 to get property >HTMLIFrameElement.cancelPopUp from http://vm-sp2010:700.
>   Source File: http://vm-sp2010/my/personal/administrator/Lists/ClockSettings/EditForm.aspx?ID=1&IsDlg=1
>   Line: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you have not properly defined your alternate access mappings. Your web application might listen on port 80 and port 700 but only one has been defined in the AAM settings. Internet Explorer uses integrated authentication and logs on to the other web application automatically. Firefox and Chrome are not able to log onto the different site if integrated security is not enabled.

Comment: The problem is indeed down to AAM, but the cause of the error is because javascript can't access iframe contents that exist in another domain (in this case, the port number is different, so as far as the DOM is concerned, a different site).